# How get sum of count when using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [ReferredDoctor_ID] , [count] , SUM([count]) [returns]
FROM (SELECT O.[ReferredDoctor_ID], COUNT(1) [count]
      FROM [dbo].[Order] O WITH (NOLOCK)  
      WHERE O.agency_id = @agency_id AND O.Trash = 0  AND
            O.DateCreatedByServer BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
      GROUP BY O.[ReferredDoctor_ID] 
     ) dd
GROUP BY [ReferredDoctor_ID] , [count]
ORDER BY [count] DESC
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  Perhaps sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both the count and the overall sum, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT O.[ReferredDoctor_ID], COUNT(*) as cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total_cnt
FROM [dbo].[Order] O 
WHERE O.agency_id = @agency_id AND O.Trash = 0  AND
      O.DateCreatedByServer BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
GROUP BY O.ReferredDoctor_ID;
```